# measure of a function defined on subsets of the irrational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

We all know the famous example of the Dirichlet function, namely

$$ D_{[0,1]}= \begin{cases}1 & \text{if } x\in\Bbb I \\
0 & \text{if } x\in\Bbb Q \end{cases}$$

It can be shown through additivity of the exterior measure and the zero measure of any $Q\subset \Bbb Q$ that the integral of this function on $ [0,1]$ is indeed $1$.

Let us construct a new set in the following way:

1. We choose the set $[0,1]$ and remove all $x\in[0,1]$ such that $x\in \Bbb Q$, since this is a zero measure set.
2. we then define two subsets $I_1$ and $I_2$ of $I=[0,1]\cap \Bbb I$ in this way:
   we define two properties, let's say $P_1$ and $P_2$, such that, for every two elements satisfying $P_1$ we can find an element satisfying $P_2$ that lies between the two previous points, and viceversa. In other words, both sets are dense in each other.
   I haven't been able to find such a property by myself, and I don't even know if such a property could exist, so I'd like some clarification on that as well and maybe an example.
3. We assign every point that satisfy $P_1$ to $I_1$ and every point that satisfy $P_2$ to $I_2$
4. We define the function $f$
   $$ f_{[0,1]}= \begin{cases}1 & \text{if } x\in I_1 \\
   0 & \text{if } x\in I_2 \end{cases}$$ (we could have assigned other values, like 2 and 25, it doesn't matter)

My question is: what is the value of the integral of this function? is it computable? Is the underlying set $I$ measurable? if so, what would be its measure? does it depend on the kind of properties we define?

thanks

Comment: It all depends on how you define $I_1$ and $I_2$.  If $I_2$ is numbers of the form $\sqrt 2 + q$ for $q$ rational then you something similar to what happened with the rationals and the integration is essentially the same as before.  If $I_1$ is numbers of the form $\sqrt 2 + q$ for $q$ rational then you get something similar except $0$ and $1$ swap.  But there are many other possibilities too